# C# GUI Within DLL

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface

I've been struggling with a problem that I have for days now and I just cannot find a solution.

My problem is I have an application that calls a DLL (Metatrader 4 is the application).  The DLL receives arrays and integers from Metatrader, does a lot of calculations, and returns a double value to Metatrader.

The C# DLL looks as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

using Encog;
using Encog.Neural.Networks;
using Encog.Neural.Networks.Layers;
using Encog.Neural.Networks.Training;
using Encog.Neural.Networks.Training.Propagation.Resilient;
using Encog.Engine.Network.Activation;
using Encog.ML.Data;
using Encog.ML.Data.Basic;
using Encog.App.Quant.Indicators;
using Encog.App.Quant;
using Encog.Neural.NeuralData;
using System.Data;
using System.ComponentModel;


namespace NN_1_DLL
{
public static class UnmanagedExports
{


    static DataTable dt;
    static DataGridView gridview;
    static Form frm;

    static double NeuralOutput = 0;

    static double LowNormalize;
    static double HighNormalize;
    static double dataHigh;
    static double dataLow;

    static int NNInputs;
    static int NNOutputs;

    static double[] trainingData;
    static double[] neuralInput;
    static int trainingDataSize;
    static int trainingSets;
    static int epochMax;
    static int hiddenLayerNeurons;


    static double[][] TRAINING_INPUT;
    static double[][] TRAINING_OUTPUT;
    static double[] NEURAL_INPUT;

    static bool isShowGUI;

    static bool FormInitiated = false;





    public static void GUI()
    {

        int i, j;


        dt = new DataTable("Table");

        for (i = 0; i < NNInputs; i++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("Input " + i, typeof(double));
        }

        dt.Columns.Add("Output", typeof(double));


        for (i = 0; i < TRAINING_INPUT.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            DataRow dataRow = dt.NewRow();

            for (j = 0; j < TRAINING_INPUT[i].GetLength(0); j++)
            {

                //dataRow["Input " + j] = TRAINING_INPUT[i][j];
                dataRow["Input " + j] = ((((dataLow - dataHigh) * TRAINING_INPUT[i][j] - HighNormalize * dataLow + dataHigh * LowNormalize) / (LowNormalize - HighNormalize)));


            }

            //dataRow["Output"] = TRAINING_OUTPUT[i][0];
            dataRow["Output"] = ((((dataLow - dataHigh) * TRAINING_OUTPUT[i][0] - HighNormalize * dataLow + dataHigh * LowNormalize) / (LowNormalize - HighNormalize)));


            dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);

        }




        if (FormInitiated == false)
        {


            frm = new Form();
            frm.Name = "frm";
            frm.ControlBox = false;
            frm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            frm.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
            frm.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 600);
            frm.Show();

            gridview = new DataGridView();
            gridview.Name = "gridview";
            gridview.Height = 600;
            gridview.Width = 800;
            frm.Controls.Add(gridview);

            FormInitiated = true;

        }


        gridview.DataSource = dt;


    }




    static void PrepareData()
    {

        double[] array_input = new double[NNInputs];
        double[] array_output = new double[NNOutputs];
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int refpoint = 0;


        //PREPARE DATA FOR NEURAL NETWORK

        dataHigh = Math.Max(trainingData.Max(), neuralInput.Max());
        dataLow = Math.Min(trainingData.Min(), neuralInput.Min());


        for (i = 0; i < trainingData.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            trainingData[i] = (((trainingData[i] - dataLow) / (dataHigh - dataLow)) * (HighNormalize - LowNormalize) + LowNormalize);
        }

        NEURAL_INPUT = new double[neuralInput.GetLength(0)];

        for (i = 0; i < neuralInput.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            NEURAL_INPUT[i] = (((neuralInput[i] - dataLow) / (dataHigh - dataLow)) * (HighNormalize - LowNormalize) + LowNormalize);
        }




        TRAINING_INPUT = new double[trainingSets][];
        TRAINING_OUTPUT = new double[trainingSets][];

        for (i = 0; i < trainingSets; i++)
        {
            refpoint = (i * (NNInputs + NNOutputs));

            for (j = refpoint; j < refpoint + NNInputs; j++)
            {

                array_input[j - refpoint] = trainingData[j];
            }

            refpoint = refpoint + NNInputs;

            for (j = refpoint; j < refpoint + NNOutputs; j++)
            {

                array_output[j - refpoint] = trainingData[j];
            }


            TRAINING_INPUT[i] = array_input;
            TRAINING_OUTPUT[i] = array_output;

            array_input = new double[NNInputs];
            array_output = new double[NNOutputs];

        }



    }




    static void ComputeNN()
    {

        int i = 0;

        BasicNetwork network = new BasicNetwork();
        network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationTANH(), true, NNInputs));
        network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationTANH(), true, hiddenLayerNeurons));
        network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationTANH(), true, NNOutputs));

        network.Structure.FinalizeStructure();
        network.Reset();

        IMLDataSet trainingSet = new BasicMLDataSet(TRAINING_INPUT, TRAINING_OUTPUT);

        ITrain train = new ResilientPropagation(network, trainingSet);

        int epoch = 1;


        do
        {
            train.Iteration();

            epoch++;
        } while ((epoch < epochMax));




        INeuralData input = new Encog.Neural.Data.Basic.BasicNeuralData(NNInputs);
        for (i = 0; i < NNInputs; i++)
        {
            input[i] = NEURAL_INPUT[i];
        }

        IMLData output = network.Compute(input);
        NeuralOutput = ((((dataLow - dataHigh) * output[0] - HighNormalize * dataLow + dataHigh * LowNormalize) / (LowNormalize - HighNormalize)));

    }






    [DllExport("NNExportDLL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    static double NNExportDLL([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)] double[] training_data, int training_data_size, int inputs, int outputs, int  training_sets, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 2)] double[] neural_input, int epoch_Max, int hidden_Layer_Neurons, double Low_Normalize, double High_Normalize, int ShowGUI)
    {

        //Define some global variables

        LowNormalize = new double();
        HighNormalize = new double();
        NNInputs = new int();
        NNOutputs = new int();
        trainingData = new double[training_data_size];
        trainingDataSize = new int();
        trainingSets = new int();
        epochMax = new int();
        hiddenLayerNeurons = new int();
        neuralInput = new double[inputs];

        LowNormalize = Low_Normalize;
        HighNormalize = High_Normalize;
        NNInputs = inputs;
        NNOutputs = outputs;
        trainingData = training_data;
        trainingDataSize = training_data_size;
        trainingSets = training_sets;
        epochMax = epoch_Max;
        hiddenLayerNeurons = hidden_Layer_Neurons;
        neuralInput = neural_input;

        if (ShowGUI == 1) { isShowGUI = true; } else { isShowGUI = false; }

        if (isShowGUI == true)
        {
            PrepareData();
            ComputeNN();
            GUI();
        }


        if (isShowGUI == false)
        {
            PrepareData();
            ComputeNN();
        }


        return (NeuralOutput); 


    }

}
}
```

I have to use threading due to the fact that the GUI freezes during calculations, there is absolutely no response from the GUI().  I have tried the backgroundworker class but the DLL returns the value before the functions are completed and the GUI still freezes.

The GUI() is built from the data calculated in the PrepareData() and ComputeNN() function, so they have to be executed first before the GUI() function is executed.  Also the PrepareData() and ComputeNN() functions must be completed before the function returns the double value to Metatrader.

I have absolutely no experience with threading and GUIs within DLL's, so would appreciate any advice!

**Maybe I'm trying to do something that is either impossible or stupid.  The whole reason for the GUI is for me to see if the data is calculated as it is supposed to be (more of a way for me to debug the code).  I will later on add charts and such to visualize the training process/data.  If there is a better way to do this please let me know!***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the GUI thread's dispatcher:

```
double d = 0d;
App.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>{ 
        d = callYourMethod();
    }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal);
```

you can look at this [link](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/working-with-the-wpf-dispatcher) for a tutorial on the WPF dispatcher.

Give the BackgroundWorker another try. Declare these static fields:

```
private static BackgroundWorker prepareDataBW;
private static BackgroundWorker computeNnBW;


private static bool isFinishedPrepareData;
private static bool isFinishedComputeNN;

private static Action BackgroundWorkerFinishedAction;
```

and these static methods (the event handlers):

```
        static void prepareDataBW_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            isFinishedPrepareData = true;
            BackgroundWorkerFinishedAction();
        }
        static void computeNnBW_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            isFinishedComputeNN = true;
            BackgroundWorkerFinishedAction();
        }
        static void BackgroundWorkerFinishedAction()
        {
            if(isFinishedComputeNN && isFinishedPrepareData && isShowGUI)
            {
                UpdateUI();
            }
            else if(isFinishedComputeNN && isFinishedPrepareData)
            {
                ShowGUI();
            }
        }
```

then instead of:

```
    if (ShowGUI == 1) //Show GUI
    {
        PrepareData();
        ComputeNN();
        ShowGUI();
    }

    else

    {
        PrepareData();
        ComputeNN();
    }
```

try something like this:

```
        prepareDataBW = new BackgroundWorker();
        prepareDataBW.DoWork += delegate { 
        prepareDataBW();
            };
            prepareDataBW.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(prepareDataBW_RunWorkerCompleted);

        computeNnBW = new BackgroundWorker();
        computeNnBW.DoWork += delegate { 
            computeNN(); 
        };
        computeNnBW.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(computeNnBW_RunWorkerCompleted);

        BackgroundWorkerFinishedAction += new Action(BackgroundWorkerFinishedAction);
        prepareDataBW.RunWorkerAsync();
        computeNnBW.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Based on all of your code, and in order to test your app you should try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

using Encog;
using Encog.Neural.Networks;
using Encog.Neural.Networks.Layers;
using Encog.Neural.Networks.Training;
using Encog.Neural.Networks.Training.Propagation.Resilient;
using Encog.Engine.Network.Activation;
using Encog.ML.Data;
using Encog.ML.Data.Basic;
using Encog.App.Quant.Indicators;
using Encog.App.Quant;
using Encog.Neural.NeuralData;
using System.Data;
using System.ComponentModel;


namespace NN_1_DLL
{
    public static class UnmanagedExports
    {

        static DataTable dt;
        static DataGridView gridview;
        static Form frm;

        static double NeuralOutput = 0;

        static double LowNormalize;
        static double HighNormalize;
        static double dataHigh;
        static double dataLow;

        static int NNInputs;
        static int NNOutputs;

        static double[] trainingData;
        static double[] neuralInput;
        static int trainingDataSize;
        static int trainingSets;
        static int epochMax;
        static int hiddenLayerNeurons;


        static double[][] TRAINING_INPUT;
        static double[][] TRAINING_OUTPUT;
        static double[] NEURAL_INPUT;

        static bool isShowGUI;

        static bool FormInitiated = false;


        public static BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

        public static void Main()
        {
            initForm();
            bw.DoWork += delegate
            {
                double d = NNExportDLL(
                new double[] { 2d, 3.4, 5d }, 3, 2, 2, 1, new double[] { 2d, 3d, 5d, 6d }, 3, 100, 4d, 8d, 1);
                Console.Write(d);
            };
            Application.Run(frm);
        }


        public static void initForm()
        {
            if (FormInitiated == false)
            {
                frm = new Form();
                frm.Name = "frm";
                frm.ControlBox = false;
                frm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                frm.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
                frm.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 700);
                //frm.ShowDialog();

                FlowLayoutPanel flp = new FlowLayoutPanel();
                flp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

                frm.Controls.Add(flp);

                gridview = new DataGridView();
                gridview.Name = "gridview";
                gridview.Height = 600;
                gridview.Width = 800;
                flp.Controls.Add(gridview);

                Button b = new Button();
                b.Text = "Refresh";
                b.Click += new EventHandler(b_Click);
                b.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
                flp.Controls.Add(b);

                FormInitiated = true;
            }

        }

        static void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();

        }

        static void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted -= new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
            RefreshData();
        }


        static void RefreshData()
        {
            int i, j;
            dt = new DataTable("Table");
            for (i = 0; i < NNInputs; i++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add("Input " + i, typeof(double));
            }
            dt.Columns.Add("Output", typeof(double));
            for (i = 0; i < TRAINING_INPUT.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                DataRow dataRow = dt.NewRow();
                for (j = 0; j < TRAINING_INPUT[i].GetLength(0); j++)
                {
                    //dataRow["Input " + j] = TRAINING_INPUT[i][j];
                    dataRow["Input " + j] = ((((dataLow - dataHigh) * TRAINING_INPUT[i][j] - HighNormalize * dataLow + dataHigh * LowNormalize) / (LowNormalize - HighNormalize)));
                }
                //dataRow["Output"] = TRAINING_OUTPUT[i][0];
                dataRow["Output"] = ((((dataLow - dataHigh) * TRAINING_OUTPUT[i][0] - HighNormalize * dataLow + dataHigh * LowNormalize) / (LowNormalize - HighNormalize)));
                dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);
            }
            gridview.DataSource = dt;
        }

        static void PrepareData()
        {

            double[] array_input = new double[NNInputs];
            double[] array_output = new double[NNOutputs];
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            int refpoint = 0;


            //PREPARE DATA FOR NEURAL NETWORK

            dataHigh = Math.Max(trainingData.Max(), neuralInput.Max());
            dataLow = Math.Min(trainingData.Min(), neuralInput.Min());


            for (i = 0; i < trainingData.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                trainingData[i] = (((trainingData[i] - dataLow) / (dataHigh - dataLow)) * (HighNormalize - LowNormalize) + LowNormalize);
            }

            NEURAL_INPUT = new double[neuralInput.GetLength(0)];

            for (i = 0; i < neuralInput.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                NEURAL_INPUT[i] = (((neuralInput[i] - dataLow) / (dataHigh - dataLow)) * (HighNormalize - LowNormalize) + LowNormalize);
            }




            TRAINING_INPUT = new double[trainingSets][];
            TRAINING_OUTPUT = new double[trainingSets][];

            for (i = 0; i < trainingSets; i++)
            {
                refpoint = (i * (NNInputs + NNOutputs));

                for (j = refpoint; j < refpoint + NNInputs; j++)
                {

                    array_input[j - refpoint] = trainingData[j];
                }

                refpoint = refpoint + NNInputs;

                for (j = refpoint; j < refpoint + NNOutputs; j++)
                {
                    if (trainingData.Length - 1 >= j)
                    {
                        array_output[j - refpoint] = trainingData[j];
                    }
                }


                TRAINING_INPUT[i] = array_input;
                TRAINING_OUTPUT[i] = array_output;

                array_input = new double[NNInputs];
                array_output = new double[NNOutputs];

            }



        }

        static void ComputeNN()
        {

            int i = 0;

            BasicNetwork network = new BasicNetwork();
            network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationTANH(), true, NNInputs));
            network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationTANH(), true, hiddenLayerNeurons));
            network.AddLayer(new BasicLayer(new ActivationTANH(), true, NNOutputs));

            network.Structure.FinalizeStructure();
            network.Reset();

            IMLDataSet trainingSet = new BasicMLDataSet(TRAINING_INPUT, TRAINING_OUTPUT);

            ITrain train = new ResilientPropagation(network, trainingSet);

            int epoch = 1;


            do
            {
                train.Iteration();

                epoch++;
            } while ((epoch < epochMax));




            INeuralData input = new Encog.Neural.Data.Basic.BasicNeuralData(NNInputs);
            for (i = 0; i < NNInputs; i++)
            {
                input[i] = NEURAL_INPUT[i];
            }

            IMLData output = network.Compute(input);
            NeuralOutput = ((((dataLow - dataHigh) * output[0] - HighNormalize * dataLow + dataHigh * LowNormalize) / (LowNormalize - HighNormalize)));

        }

        [DllExport("NNExportDLL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        static double NNExportDLL(
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)] double[] training_data,
            int training_data_size, int inputs, int outputs, int training_sets,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 2)] double[] neural_input,
            int epoch_Max,
            int hidden_Layer_Neurons,
            double Low_Normalize,
            double High_Normalize,
            int ShowGUI)
        {

            //Define some global variables

            LowNormalize = new double();
            HighNormalize = new double();
            NNInputs = new int();
            NNOutputs = new int();
            trainingData = new double[training_data_size];
            trainingDataSize = new int();
            trainingSets = new int();
            epochMax = new int();
            hiddenLayerNeurons = new int();
            neuralInput = new double[inputs];

            LowNormalize = Low_Normalize;
            HighNormalize = High_Normalize;
            NNInputs = inputs;
            NNOutputs = outputs;
            trainingData = training_data;
            trainingDataSize = training_data_size;
            trainingSets = training_sets;
            epochMax = epoch_Max;
            hiddenLayerNeurons = hidden_Layer_Neurons;
            neuralInput = neural_input;

            if (ShowGUI == 1) { isShowGUI = true; } else { isShowGUI = false; }


            PrepareData();
            ComputeNN();

            return (NeuralOutput);


        }

    }
}
```

the main problem was actually your trying to run the frm.show() without using Application.Run.

Another edit: don't forget to substitute what's in the bw.DoWork delegate with your own logic.

Comment: Hey there Matt, thank you for the answer!  I have absolutely no idea what that code does or how I can implement it.  Please explain a bit more... :)

Comment: are you using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: I would even check out this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx. It's more technical, but near the end it explains how to substitute the Dispatcher with the BackgroundWorker for use on the UI thread.

Comment: The problem that I'm having with using separate threads is the dll function returns a value before the operations are completed.  There is not way I can "stop" the function from returning before the threads are finished.  I have tried a while (bla bla bla is busy) {} but the app crashes if I do that.

Comment: Wow thank you for all your effort!  C# gives an error with BackgroundWorkerFinishedAction().  It says there is an ambiguity between the void function and the action.

Comment: sorry, just rename the function to BackgroundWorkerFinishedMethod (for example), and update the reference BackgroundWorkerFinishedAction += new Action(BackgroundWorkerFinishedMethod);

Comment: As previously the dll returns before the functions are completely executed, also the GUI still hangs...  Aye this thing is driving me nuts.  But thank you anyways for your help really appreciate it

Comment: i'ld like to be able to help you.. do you think you could post all of your (at least the stuff you replace with the comments explaining the logic)?

Comment: Ok I will add all the code in my original post.  I might be a bit confusing since I'm using the Encog neural network framework

Comment: I updated the code, the code is the old code without your modifications

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help! :)  I don't understand why is there a Main() method?  The DLL call will automatically use the dll export function how is the Main() function executed?  Also I'm a bit confused on how to integrate the DLL export function with the code you posted...  I really apologise for sounding like an idiod

Comment: You don't yet have enough point's to chat on SO yet, so if you'ld like i could give you a hand through skype or google chat?

Comment: The main method is there as the entry point of the application in the test environment (i dont have the dll or program you will be calling from).  Note that in .net a dll and an exe are basically the same, except for the fact the an exe points to a start up method.  In this case I created a new project (using SharpDevelop) from a template (the template is of a console application); I then pasted in all of your code; then added the references to the encog and dllexport assemblies; then added a static Main method;

Comment: and lastly went in the the properties of the project, the "application" tab, and set the root namespace to "NN_1_DLL", and the startup object to "UnmanagedExports" (in order for an object to be a Startup object it has to have a static Main method).  Note that from the "application" tab you decide what type of assembly you will output by changing the output type (so in your current case, to make my example work you will need to change the output type to "Console Application").

Comment: I got it working by doing all calculations on the main thread, and moving the gui to a separate thread:


                Thread GUIThread = new Thread(() => { Application.Run(frm); });
                GUIThread.Start();